# what does !function in Javascript mean?

Tags: javascript

Sorry for posting this but  !function is not google-able and I did not find it in my JavaScript code.

Here is how Twitter uses it:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://google.com" data-text="Google says">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

from https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is short-hand or alternative of [self-invoking anonymous function](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/):

```
(function(){
  // code
})();
```

Can be written:

```
!function(){
  // code
}();
```

You can also use `+` instead of `!`.

If you simply did:

```
function(){
  // code
}();
```

That will create problems, that's why you need to add `!` before it which turns the ***function declaration*** into ***function expression***.

[Quoting docs, section 12.4:](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

> An ExpressionStatement cannot start with the function keyword because
>   that might make it ambiguous with a FunctionDeclaration.

To better understand the concept, you should check out:

- [Function Declarations vs. Function Expressions](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)

Comment: Interesting. When is a self-invoking anonymous function useful? How is it different from simply executing the statements inside?

Comment: @netvope: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript

Comment: I see. Thanks. Would be nice if Javascript supports scoping with just the braces (like in C++)

Comment: @netvope ECMAScript 6 (a.k.a. ES 2015) does support block level scope with the `let` and `const` declarations.

Answer (score 6):

they're negating the result, not the function itself:

```
!function( x ){ return x }( true );
!true
false
```

In reality, it's a slightly compressed form of:

```
(function(){}())
```

since it requires 1 less character.  The reason it's needed is that you can't call a function declaration directly, e.g. this is invalid:

```
function(){}()
```

but adding the `!` at the beginning turns it into a function `expression` and makes it work.

Comment: Interesting technique...

Comment: "negating the result" is misleading, @Twisol's answer is more accurate

Comment: @ŠimeVidas -- I have a feeling this is generated code looking for self-invoking function patterns since it does save 1 character :)

Comment: @FactorMystic -- I explained the same thing :)  The OP is confused because they think it means "not function"

Comment: This is a good example of how the ! has two meanings. In this case, the ! should be interpreted as self-invoking function, not as negation.

Comment: Oops, I meant to write more, but hit enter too soon.
---
This is a good example of how the ! has two meanings. In this case, the ! is interpreted as self-invoking function, not as negation, since the return value of the function is thrown away.  
      
If the return value were used in a larger statement, then the ! would not be needed to self-invoke the method, so it is interpreted as negation. Both of these work and display different results.  
alert(function(x){return x}(true))  
alert(!function(x){return x}(true))

Comment: Does anybody know if the parser actually evaluates the negation before throwing the result away?

Is saving a single character the only reason to prefer this to wrapping the function in parens?

Comment: @Jonz -- Yes, it evaluates it before throwing it away, not like it's an expensive op.  It also prevents errors from code that basically evaluates to: `(function(){})()(function(){})()` -- The lack of `;` in the middle of that means the 2nd function is passed to the result of the first.  Not desired behavior usually and results in an error or really weird behavior.  `!` or any binary op prevents this

Comment: @downeyt The `!` does not have two meanings. When the JS runtime sees `!` it knows that it can only mean (because there is only one meaning for `!`) logical negation and because of that, the JS runtime understands that you can only negate an expression, not a statement, so the remainder of the instruction is treated as such. In this usage, the result of the expression doesn't matter and is discarded. There is no dual-meaning.

Comment: Why are you replying to a 5 year old conversation?  :/

Comment: Because it's the right thing to do :-) . It is never too late to put something straight. If he hadn't corrected it, I would have.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually used to work around a quirk in the JavaScript syntax. This gives a syntax error:

```
function() {
}();
```

It's read as a function declaration (like `function foo () {}`), rather than a function expression. So adding the ! before it, or wrapping it in parentheses, forces the parser to understand that it's an expression.

Comment: It's not a quirk of syntax. It's just syntax.